# Star Rating render instead of simple select_tag drop down render

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have this span:

```
<span class="rating">
  <tr>
    <td>Quality</td>
    <td><%= select_tag :quality,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { multiple: false } %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td><%= select_tag :cost,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { multiple: false } %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td><%= select_tag :time,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { multiple: false } %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Experience</td>
    <td><%= select_tag :experience,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { :multiple => false } %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Communication</td>
    <td><%= select_tag :communication,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { :multiple => false } %></td>
  </tr>
</span>
```

that is used for setting some ratings parameter of the user. It renders in just drop down lists which is not nice. I decided to use star based rating and with a bit of search i found this [nice article](http://everythingfrontend.com/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html).

I did place all the CSS properly and I can see that the stars **should** show up and render as:

```
<span class="rating">
<input type="radio" class="rating-input"
    id="rating-input-1-5" name="rating-input-1">
<label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input"
    id="rating-input-1-4" name="rating-input-1">
<label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input"
    id="rating-input-1-3" name="rating-input-1">
<label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input"
    id="rating-input-1-2" name="rating-input-1">
<label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input"
    id="rating-input-1-1" name="rating-input-1">
<label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
</span>
```

I tried with couple ways, but I am not sure how I will change this: `<%= select_tag :quality,  options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), { multiple: false } %>` into the radio, of stars, input.

The closest I reached was:

```
    <td>
      <% [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ].each do |quality| %>
        <br><%= radio_button_tag 'quality', quality, @quality == quality, class: "rating-input" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating_#{quality}", quality.humanize %>
        <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
      <% end %>
    </td>
```

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
1..5.each do |rate|
  radio_button_tag 'quality', quality, resource.quality == quality, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating_quality_#{rate}"
  label_tag "rating_quality_#{rate}"
end
```

I did not include the `<%%>` tags for readability.